# WPF Clipboard with Multiple Formats

Tags: wpf, clipboard

I have a situation where I want to allow a user to copy a combination of text and images to the clipboard.  I then want to access this in my WPF app so I've been using `System.Windows.Clipboard`.  This class has a method called `GetDataObject()` returning an `IDataObject`.  Then on the `IDataObject` I can call `GetData()` passing in the format I require (image, text, etc.).

However, I want to be able to get everything that was copied in the correct order.  So if I have an image embedded between two paragraphs of text `GetData()` can return me all the text or all images but won't tell me where in the text the images sit.

**So, does anyone know how to access text and embedded images in the correct order from the clipboard within a WPF app?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask for a clipboard format  that retains these contextual information. Such as text/html. Wether such a format is available highly depends on the application that is used to copy the data in the first place.